# Can I sync my Evernote bookmarks into a major browser's bookmarks bar?

Tags: bookmarks, evernote, synchronization, browser-addons

Call me crazy, but I think the bookmark bar provides a good purpose.  It's right there, and that's invaluable to UX — no second layer required.

But vanishingly few services care to integrate, it seems.  Right now, I am mostly looking for a way to sync evernote bookmarks into the browser's bookmarks bar/menu/etc.

I have special conditions:

- Chrome's sync is not viable because it's not available behind typical corp firewalls.
- 3rd party services like Evernote seem to be small enough to avoid corp firewall policies.
- XMarks is just a travesty (as of today 2014-04).

---

*On a conceptual note*: is the lack of tools caused by poor control / UX for syncing?  ...e.g. deciding which changes to keep between devices... which leads to low perceived value of such sync services?  I would understand that, considering that a web-app without sync needs would be cheaper to produce.